# Proof of the following properties of linear transformations $T(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ and $T(-\mathbf{v})=-\mathbf{v}$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

The Problem:

Let $V, W$ be vector spaces over a field $F$, and $T:V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Show that $T(\mathbf{0}) = \mathbf{0}$ and $T(-\mathbf{v}) = -T(\mathbf{v})$ for all $\mathbf{v} \in V$.

My solution:
Because $T$ is a linear operator we count with the following properties:

$$T(\mathbf{v}_1 + \mathbf{v}_2) = T(\mathbf{v}_1)+T(\mathbf{v}_2) \ \forall \mathbf{v}_1, \mathbf{v}_2 \in V$$
$$T(\alpha \mathbf{v}) = \alpha T(\mathbf{v}) \ \forall \mathbf{v} \in V, \alpha \in F $$

We can use the properties of vectors to do the following:
$$T(\mathbf{0}) = T(0 \cdot \mathbf{v}) = 0 \cdot T(\mathbf{v}) = \mathbf{0}$$
$$T(-\mathbf{v}) = T(-1 \cdot \mathbf{v}) = -1 \cdot T(\mathbf{v}) = -T(\mathbf{v})$$

Is this enough? For some reason it doesn't seem rigurous enough for me.

Comment: That's fine.  These are so basic properties, there's very little to prove in them

Comment: Seems good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Both proofs are correct. Well done!